# Python: Iterate over all days in a month

Tags: python, date, iteration

Is there a simple way to iterate over all days in a given month?

I would like to have a method where the object I'm iterating over has the days as `datetime.date` objects. I have already found the `calendar` module with its `Calendar` class and respective method `itermonthdates(year, month)`.

My problem with this is that the resulting iterator contains "filler" days to represent complete weeks. For example July 2019 Ends on a Wednesday (31). so the week is incomplete and `itermonthdates()` adds the dates 1-4 August.

I DO NOT want this behavior.

My first guess is something like:

```
from calendar import Calendar, monthrange
c = Calendar()

for date in list(c.itermonthdates(2019, 7))[:monthrange(2019, 7)[1]]:
    print(date)
```

which behaves as expected, but I'm not sure if there is a nicer, more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: What is `calendar`? What is `DateTime`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist `calendar` is a standard Python module.

Comment: `calendar` as mentioned is the module named that way, part of the standart lib. Edited `DateTime` to `datetime.date` sorry for that.

Comment: You can make it somewhat tidier by using `for d in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.month == 7, c.itermonthdates(2019, 7)):` instead of the `monthrange` call. I'm not sure offhand if there's a better way using the standard library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module is designed to display calendars. You are better off using `calendar.monthlen` in combination with `datetime.date` itself to get your iterator, if you are looking for something straightforward:

```py
def date_iter(year, month):
    for i in range(1, calendar.monthlen(year, month) + 1):
        yield date(year, month, i)

for d in date_iter(2019, 12):
    print(d)
```

You can of course write the whole thing as a one-liner:

```py
for d in (date(2019, 12, i) for i in range(1, calendar.monthlen(2019, 12) + 1)):
    print(d)
```

The `monthlen` attribute appears to be a public, but undocumented attribute of `calendar` in Python 3.7. It is analogous to the second element of [`monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange), so you can replace it with `monthrange(year, month)[1]` in the code above.

Comment: `calendar.monthlen` does not exist. I think we need to stick with `calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]` .

Comment: @Chgad. It's in my python 3.7 version, but does not appear to be documented for some reason.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm using Python 3.6 and there it 'doesn't exist. If You add this to your answer I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @Chgad. Makes sense. Done

Comment: It doesn't seem to exist in Python 3.8 anymore (at least not in Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: An undocumented attribute only present in one python version should not be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @BrettHolman. I have to agree with you :)

Answer (score 13):

Just filter the `date` objects by month.

```
for d in [x for x in c.itermonthdates(2019, 7) if x.month == 7]:
```

Comment: Nitpick: Using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension would avoid the creation of an intermediate list.

Comment: True; the OP was already creating the new list, so I stuck with it.